# Report manually run tests with surefire

Tags: maven, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a series of tests I need to run from maven.  The tests are run through a series of custom created scripts, that run something like qunit, that outputs a junit style xml file that I then copy into the target/surefire-reports directory.  What I'd like to do is have the surefire plugin print the results of the tests I ran myself.  Currently surefire reports that no tests were ran (correctly as it didn't actually run the tests).

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I'd like for surefire to be able to find the junit style output files that were created by my test system and report on them. Any ideas on how to make this happen?  I know I can run the surefire-report plugin to generate an html report, but that's not what I'm looking for I already have an aggregator.

Comment: Why do you have custom created scripts? Why not using the defaults ?

Comment: Because they aren't java tests, they are tests in other languages requiring vastly different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surefire is for running the tests and then reporting them.  Since you plan on running the tests on your own and since they aren't even written in Java, I don't think it's the plugin for you.

What you want is the [Surefire Report Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/).  There's a goal named [surefire-report:report-only](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html) which should be what you need.